# How to run a method every time a class is used swift

Tags: xcode, class, swift, object

It's Julie. I'd like to ask you for help, as   age a small problem. I have a class called `Car` and there I declare a `static var carCount`. 
Now, after I create all the objects of car, I want to see how many cars are there. Thus I want to increment **carCount** every time the class is used to create a object. How can I do that? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @midpadi and @cmasinho, you should increment a count variable in your `init` method. The reason you're getting the error:

> ViewController.Car does not have a member named 'carCount'

is because you're not prefixing `carCount` with the name of your class and `carCount` is a `static` variable.

Your class should look something like this:

```
class Car {
    static var carCount = 0

    init() {
        Car.carCount++
    }
}
```

Now, when you want to find out how many `Car` objects have been instantiated you would use `Car.carCount`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. This explains everything and solves my problem. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Glad it's all sorted out! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

Increment `carCount` in the `Car` class's initializer.

Comment: @JulieDagher: In the `init` method, have a line like `carCount++`.

Comment: I do not have a init method as of now. How would i create one and what would I write into it?

Answer (score 0):

Make function to create object and increment carCount in this function

```
var carCount = 0

func createCar() {
   // code to create
   carCount += 1
}
```

Comment: then however I have to call createCar on every single instance of the Car objects. Can't you do it automatically?

Comment: @JulieDagher read information in swift book. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: yes, but when I use init() it tell me ViewController.Car does not have a member named 'carCount' ... I think this is due to the static thing. or?